# unable to create new draft programatically for published node

Tags: 7, workbench

I am using [workbench_moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module.

When I edit the node and save it using `node_save($node)` it is changing the status of actual node to draft and original node is getting unpublished.

While I want to keep original node as published and want to create new reversion in draft status.

I used below code too but it is not working form me(It is immediately publishing my changes).

```
node_save($node);
workbench_moderation_moderate($node, 'published');
```

Comment: new reversion or new revision?

Comment: Are you sure no other code is executed by custom module or rules?  How about checking the publishing status after node_save($node)?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested or checked against the [source code](http://api.drupal.psu.edu/api/drupal/modules%21contrib%21workbench_moderation%21workbench_moderation.module/function/workbench_moderation_moderate/nittany7) but I think you should try to node_load after node_save and before workbench_moderation_moderate.

```
node_save($node);
$saved_node = node_load($node->nid);
workbench_moderation_moderate($saved_node, 'published');
```